# Remove unecessary indents while keeping the relative indentation

Tags: indentation, formatting

I am looking for a transformation that would change this text:

```
    text
        indented
        text
            double
            indented
            text
        indented
        again
```

to:

```
text
    indented
    text
        double
        indented
        text
    indented
    again
```

But then wouldn't change anything if applied again.

I a nutshell, I need to keep the minimal indentation level without loosing the relative indentations of the lines. So just drop the indentations that run all along the selection.

Is there a clever way to do so ?

Comment: How do you indent your files (a tab character, 4 spaces...) ? How do you imagine the solution (a mapping used in normal mode for the whole file, in visual mode while a portion of the file is selected...) ?

Comment: @saginaw There are either only spaces or only tab characters (otherwise the problem might have no solution). I actually need to apply this to whole files, but I guess it'd be easily usable on visually selected portions as well. The algorithm looks simple: given the amount of whitespace at the beginning of each line,  stored in a vector `v`, say, subtract from `v` the minimum of `v` so that its new minimum is now zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the text linewise and then paste with `]p` with your cursor from an empty line.

```
dG]p
```

Here `]p` is doing all the hard work. `]p` will paste the text, but will adjust the indent to the current line.

For more help see:

```
:h ]p
```

Comment: Nice! This is definitely more elegant ;)

Comment: Or just `d]P` if you have selected the lines you want in visual mode.

Comment: @Loovjo If you are in visual mode make sure you use `V` (Visual Line) so that the text is deleted line-wise. Alternatively you can use Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which changes `]p` and friends to always paste line-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The following code add a mapping `<leader>s` that should do what you want on the specific file you provided, if you use spaces to indent.

```
nnoremap <leader>s :<c-u>call UnindentSpaces()<cr>

function! UnindentSpaces()

    function! GlobalUnindent()

        let line = getline('.')
        let p = match(line, '\S') - s:n
        s;^\s*;\=repeat(' ', p);

    endfunction

    let line = getline(1)
    let s:n = match(line, '\S')
    if s:n > 0
        g/^/call GlobalUnindent()
    endif

endfunction
```

Conditions in which I tested this code :

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

If you use a tab character to indent, then the following code should be used instead (`<leader>t`) :

```
nnoremap <leader>t :<c-u>call UnindentTabs()<cr>

function! UnindentTabs()

    function! GlobalUnindent()

        let line = getline('.')
        let p = match(line, '\S') - s:n
        s;^\s*;\=repeat("\t", p);

    endfunction

    let line = getline(1)
    let s:n = match(line, '\S')
    if s:n > 0
        g/^/call GlobalUnindent()
    endif

endfunction
```

Conditions in which I tested this code :

```
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

Tell me if it works for you, otherwise I'll try to modify it if I can.

---

**Edit** : if you can rely on the first character of the first line to detect whether the file use spaces or tabs for indentation, then I think you can do it with only one mapping (`<leader>u`) and one function which will cover both cases (tabs vs spaces) :

```
nnoremap <leader>u :<c-u>call Unindent()<cr>

function! Unindent()

    function! GlobalUnindent()

        let line = getline('.')
        let p = match(line, '\S') - s:n
        s;^\s*;\=repeat(s:indentchar, p);

    endfunction

    let line = getline(1)
    let s:indentchar = matchstr(line, '\%1c.')
    let s:n = match(line, '\S')

    if s:n > 0
        g/^/call GlobalUnindent()
    endif

endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I think it removes one extra level and thus looses the information. I am sorry this script uses syntaxes I was even unaware of, so I can't read it and spot the mistake. I'll have a look at it after I delved into `vim`'s doc.

Comment: Could you provide a sample text on which the code removes one extra level ? I've tested it on the sample text you gave in your first post and it seems to work, unless I misunderstood something ? Or maybe I have different settings ? My indentation settings are : `set expandtab`, `set tabstop=4`, `set shiftwidth=4`, `set softtabstop=4`. Also, I've edited the code so that you don't have to repeat the mapping in case there are more than one extra indentation level on the first line.

Comment: I was missing the `tabstop` one ! It's working perfectly now. In order words, you nailed it. Cheers :)

Comment: I'm really glad it helped you ! I've edited the answer, if you can rely on the first character of the first line to detect whether the file uses spaces or tabs for indentation, then I think you can do it with only one function and one mapping which will cover both cases.